# restrict access to panel settings in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

hello I am developing an online store for a client with wordpress and woocommerce. I wanted my client to have access to the list of all the orders that have been made, but at the same time not to have access to the woocommerce "settings" panel, to avoid misconfiguring something. Is that possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

Well there is no solution out of the box, as there is 1 WooCommerce specific role of shop manager. And it has.

> Shop Manager is a role you can give someone to manage the shop without making them an Admin. They have all the rights a customer has, and are granted the main capabilities:
>
> - `manage_woocommerce`: Gives shop managers the option to manage all settings within WooCommerce, and create/edit products.
> - `view_woocommerce_reports`: Gives them access to all WooCommerce reports.

What you can try instead is, used other third party plugins to solve this as suggested in the [documentation](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/roles-capabilities/) itself.

If you wish to modify roles and capabilities, use a third-party plugin such as:

1. [Capability Manager Enhanced](http://wordpress.org/plugins/capability-manager-enhanced/)
2. [Members](http://wordpress.org/plugins/members/)
3. [Groups](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/groups/)

Comment: im already using "user role editor" which is third party tool for modify roles and capabilities, but i'm unable to find the combination for lock the settings panel, and unlock the orders panel.